# Need help cleaning my code

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsthm

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Given $\epsilon<0$,$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-0\right|<\epsilon
\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}<\epsilon
\Leftrightarrow\ \sqrt[3]{n}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\Leftrightarrow\ n>\frac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$.
Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that 
$N > \frac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$. Then, for any $n\geq N$, we have 
$\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-0\right|= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}} 
\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{N}} < \epsilon$.
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I feel it looks messy. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you getting any errors with this code? If yes please mention the specific errors. If no (ie. the code gives you the correct output) then what do you mean by >it looks messy<? Also please try to make your code readable (at least add linebreaks where necessary.)

Answer (score 6):

Some suggestions:

- Don't squeeze too much material into any given input line. Whitespace and judiciously chosen line breaks are your friends. Not only will the input be much easier to read if you keep the input lines short and simple, but debugging the math material will be much easier and faster too, since the line number information in any given error message will refer to less material.
- Load the `mathtools` package and define an `\abs` macro.
- Since there are at least a dozen instances of `sqrt[3]{...}`, maybe define a macro called `\cuberoot`?
- The output generated by `\LeftRightArrow` doesn't possess much visual prominence. I suggest replacing all instances of `\Leftrightarrow` with `\iff` ("if and only if").
- Avoid `\frac` expressions in inline math as much as possible. Instead, use inline fractions. E.g., instead of `\frac{1}{\cuberoot{n}}`, write `1/\cuberoot{n}`.
- Unless your document is badly pressed for space, do display the important formulas more prominently by typesetting them in display-math mode.
- As @egreg has pointed out in a comment, the sentence that starts with "Therefore" doesn't sound right, as the statement "there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that $N > 1/\epsilon^{3}$" is *not* a consequence of what precedes "Therefore". I suggest replacing "Therefore" with "Because the set $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above...".
- While on the subject of semantic correctness, maybe change `Then, for any $n\geq N$` to `Then, for all $n\geq N$`, i.e., replace "any" with "all"?
- Last but not least, do replace `Given $\epsilon<0$` with `Given $\epsilon>0$`. :-)

The following code and associated screenshot implement these suggestions. First a version with all inline math; second, a version with two unnumbered math displays.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,mathtools,amsthm}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
\newcommand\cuberoot[1]{\sqrt[3]{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
Given $\epsilon>0$,
$\abs{1/\!\cuberoot{n}-0} < \epsilon
\iff 1/\!\cuberoot{n} < \epsilon
\iff \cuberoot{n} > 1/\epsilon
\iff n > 1/\epsilon^{3}$.
Because the set $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above, for 
any given $\epsilon>0$ there exists 
$N\in\mathbb N$ such that $N > 1/\epsilon^{3}$. 
Then, for all $n\geq N$, we have 
$\abs{1/\!\cuberoot{n}-0} = 
1/\!\cuberoot{n} \leq 
1/\!\cuberoot{N} < \epsilon$.
\end{proof}

\begin{proof}
Given $\epsilon>0$,
\[
\abs[\Big]{\frac{1}{\cuberoot{n}}-0} < \epsilon
\iff \frac{1}{\cuberoot{n}} < \epsilon
\iff \cuberoot{n} > \frac{1}{\epsilon}
\iff n > \frac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}\,.
\]
Because the set $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded above, for 
any given $\epsilon>0$ there exists 
$N\in\mathbb N$ such that $N > 1/\epsilon^{3}$. 
Then, for all $n\geq N$, we have 
\[
\abs[\Big]{\frac{1}{\cuberoot{n}}-0} = 
\frac{1}{\cuberoot{n}} \leq 
\frac{1}{\cuberoot{N}} < \epsilon\,. \qedhere
\]
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What is the best option of having slanted fractions in inline math: using forward slash <num>/<den> or using relevant packages?

Comment: @Diaa - I really don't know how to answer a question about what the *best* option may be for generating inline-fraction expressions. It must very much depend on the actual expressions that need to be typeset. For the present material, I'd say (immodestly!) that `1/\!\cuberoot{<x>}` must be pretty close to being optimal.

Comment: Is “therefore” semantically sound in the proof? The existence of *N* is not a consequence of the previous argument.

Comment: @egreg - I was wondering about that too... But, since I'm not a mathematician, just an econometrician, I decided to gloss over that point. But now that I have some backup from a real [!] mathematician, I'll update my answer to raise this matter explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

There is not much to clean-up ... maybe to declare paired delimiter as defined in the `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsthm,
            mathtools}                      % <---
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert} % <---

\begin{document}
    \begin{proof}
Given $\epsilon>0$, $\abs*{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-0}<\epsilon
\Leftrightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}<\epsilon
\Leftrightarrow\ \sqrt[3]{n}>\frac{1}{\epsilon}
\Leftrightarrow\ n>\frac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$.
Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N\in\mathbb N$ such that
$N > \frac{1}{\epsilon^{3}}$. Then, for any $n\geq N$, we have
$\abs*{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}-0}= \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{n}}
\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{N}} < \epsilon$.
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

[image]